# Usage of a verb 希望する

Tags: usage, verbs

While filling in the application I have met the next sentence:

- ｢コースガイド」から**希望する**大学を選ぶこと｡
  There was also a translation into English:
- Please choose the universities that you wish to attend from among those listed in the“Course Guide.”

But, it was the first time for me, when I have met the verb **希望する**. I know the word 希望 and it's meaning "hope", but not the verb.

1) I am not even sure, how to translate it. For ex.: 大学を**希望します** ?
2) Also I am confused, in which situations (except this application, where I need to fill in a chosen school) can I use this verb **希望する**. Is it very formal? Is there any situations, whe this verb can suit?

I hope, my question is clear.Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: As an example of when not to use 希望する, you would not use it if you were saying your last sentence in Japanese.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I am not sure, if I have understood what you wanted to say.. Could you please specify more and also give some example if possible?

Comment: l'électeur means that 希望する would not be a good fit for the 'hope' in 'I hope my question is clear'

Comment: Oh, now I see. l'électeur, oals, thank you both a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When someone says 「希望する大学」, it implicitly means 「(進学を)希望する大学」, hence, "wish to attend" (although, it should be "hope to attend" to be more accurate). When you say 「大学を希望します」, it is translated to "I hope for a college," which sounds a bit strange. A better way to say it would be 「大学進学を希望します」.

I don't think 希望する is very formal, but a more informal way of saying it would probably be 進みたい or 行きたい.